# How do you reprogram an XMEGA after you have disabled the `RESET` pin using the `RSTDISBL` fuse?

Tags: xmega, atxmega

With chips like the ATMEGA and ATTINY you can use high voltage programming even after the `RESET` pin has been disabled using the `RSTDISBL` fuse, but the XMEGA family does not seem to have a high voltage programming mode, so how do you program one of these chips after setting the `RSTDISBL` fuse?

Answer (score 2):

The PDI functionality of the pin is still active on an XMEGA even if the `RESET` functionality is disabled via the `RSTDISBL` fuse. You can program the chip using a normal PDI connection.

How does it do this? There is a dance between the PDI clock and data pins that puts the chip into programming mode without needed an external reset. From the datasheets:

> #### Enabling
>
> The PDI physical layer must be enabled before use. This is
>   done by first forcing the PDI_DATA line high for a period longer than
>   the equivalent external reset minimum pulse width (refer to device
>   datasheet for external reset pulse width data). This will disable the
>   RESET functionality of the Reset pin, if not already disabled by the
>   fuse settings.
>
> Next, continue to keep the PDI_DATA line high for 16 PDI_CLK cycles.
>   The first PDI_CLK cycle must start no later than 100μs after the RESET
>   functionality of the Reset pin is disabled. If this does not occur in
>   time, the enabling procedure must start over again.